# Math using dynamic getters in extjs view

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a window who's height and width I'd like to set by percentage of the screen height instead of a static number.

I looked it up and saw that I can use `Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height` and `Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width` to get the screen height. I'm good there.

I then set the height and width properties using those paths and multiplied by an arbitrary decimal:

```
Ext.define("Registration.view.events.details.EventDetails",{
    extend: "Ext.window.Window",
    xtype: 'eventdetails',


    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,

    height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height * .8,
    width: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width * .8,

...
```

Works.

I then tried to abstract those decimals out to default config values and then use the dynamically generated getters in their place. This is where it breaks:

```
Ext.define("Registration.view.events.details.EventDetails",{
    extend: "Ext.window.Window",
    xtype: 'eventdetails',


    // Creates my getter methods
    config:{
        defaultHeightPercentage: 0.8,
        defaultWidthPercentage: 0.8
    },


    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,

    // This doesn't work
    height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height * this.getDefaultHeightPercentage(),
    width: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width * this.getDefaultWidthPercentage(),

...
```

Is there some reason I can't do the math in this method? I tried wrapping the entire equation in parens thinking that may fix the issue ( e.g. `height: ( Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height * this.getDefaultHeightPercentage() ),`) but it does not.

How would I accomplish this.

[Here's a fiddle of what I'm running into](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/r3j) if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is not the math, but the scope. 
In the class definition you cant't use `this` (outside a function) to refer to your instance. I tried, in your fiddle, the following code and it worked pretty fine:

```
initComponent : function() {
    var me = this;

    me.height = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height * me.getDefaultHeightPercentage();
    me.width = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width * me.getDefaultWidthPercentage();

    me.callParent(arguments);
},
```